# Difference between Across the Line and Line to Earth

Tags: capacitor

I have to make a reverse engineering. I have two different type of capacitors. What do the Across-The-Line X2 and Line-To-Earth Y2 mean? And what are the differences between them. I searched it but i couldn't find a certain answer.

Comment: can you post a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X type capacitors are designed not to fail short circuit and hence cause a massive curent flow and risk of fail. Y type caps are there for personal safety and should not fail and thus cause risk to anyone touching the chassis of some equipment: -

[image]

X2 and Y2 are a bit smaller and cheaper than the original X and Y capacitors. [Here](http://www.justradios.com/safetytips.html) is a fairly user-friendy site that gives more details.

Comment: Two more questions. Why X2's test voltage is two times of its normal voltage Y2's test voltage is ten times of its normal voltage and what happens if we put Y2 instead of X2?

Comment: Y caps are to prevent electrocution hence they are more likely to be more stringently tested AND, of course you can replace an X with a y.